# How to include custom claims from my db into JWT issued by ADB2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We have a situation where we have access control list maintained in our database. Its configurable and changes on a regular basis.

I want to include things that user can access into JWT issued by adb2c during the sign in.

I see there are extensions where adb2c can call my api endpoint for custom claims during the sign in, but there are 2 issues i dont see a solution for:

1. docs say that claims must be defined before in adb2c meaning i cannot add new claims unless i added them into adb2c first
2. claims extension api calls work only on initial sign in and not on getting new jwt using refresh token.

Am i missing something or is there some other way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. docs say that claims must be defined before in adb2c meaning i cannot add new claims unless i added them into adb2c first

That's right, if you're using user flows the claim must be either a built-in claim or a custom attribute you've added, and it must be selected in the **Application claims** configuration of the user flow.

If you're using custom policies then the claim must just be defined in your custom policy, you don't need to create it as a custom attribute as well.

**Important** this is talking about the claim that will hold your value in the token rather than individual values within the claim. So if you had an ACL that contained `admin` and `user` and you wanted to include that in the token as a string, you could add an `acl` custom attribute and have your API populate that; if you later added another value (say, `superuser`) you wouldn't need to change anything in B2C because it would just be another value mapped to your existing `acl` claim.

> 2. claims extension api calls work only on initial sign in and not on getting new jwt using refresh token.

For user flows that's right, they will only provide your with a refreshed version (i.e. timestamps updated) of the originally issued token.

Custom policies however [support custom refresh token journeys](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/refresh-token-journey) so you can have the ACL re-read each time a token is refreshed and up-to-date values returned in the new token.

If you need the token contents to be updated when refreshed then you'll have to use custom policies. See [the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-overview) for more info about the differences between the two.

Comment: oh, so you are saying i could define claim `acl` in adb2c and then fill it in with comma separated values, e.g.? if so, do you maybe know if i could fill it in with json collection? would it work? reason asking is that i want to have it work with `Authorize` attribute (`HasClaim`).

Comment: Yep, exactly that. If you're using user flows then you can only use string, int, and boolean values. If you're using custom policies you can also use string arrays, so your comma separated list could be an array of string values instead. With custom policies you could use a JSON collection as long as it's only strings. B2C doesn't have a claim type of a collection of objects and can't output that in the token, the only way you'd be able to support such a complex collection is if you serialised it to a string and returned the string in the token.

Comment: and how would that work with `Authorize` attribute on controllers or minimal API endpoints? would it work at all?

Comment: It depends on how you're setting up your authorization logic in ASP.NET. If you use a [policy-based approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-7.0) then you can set up a policy that will look at the custom claim, potentially deserialize any JSON and use that. Or you could use [mapping or transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/claims?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to take the incoming serialized JSON/array/CSV value and map it to the roles expected by `AuthorizeAttribute`.

Comment: that makes perfect sense. thanks a lot for your effort!

Comment: No worries, it's probably worth me point out as a last thing - if you're using custom policies then you could have the logic/API response map to a claim called `roles` (or possibly `role`, I forget which `AuthorizeAttribute` actually checks) in the custom policy itself and return that as part of the token so you don't have to map anything in ASP.NET. It all depends on whether you want to use custom policies, what you can return from your API, and how complex the parsing logic is.